# Load new posts to the top - Upward scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am working on a site where new posts are published in (more or less) real-time. Since I don't want the posts to constantly scroll down when new ones are posted I was thinking to load new posts 'on top' of the other posts. If the user wants to see the new posts s/he has to scroll up instead of down.

I've been looking around for ideas on how to achieve this but wasn't lucky so far. Does anyone has an idea how to get started?

Many thanks!
D

P.S. I do not want to display a message (like twitter) that says 'New posts'. I kind of want the posts to load in instantly.

Comment: I think we need more information on your site and how it works to answer this.  Maybe even a link to it?

Comment: I am working on this site locally so I can't provide you with a link at this moment. I am not sure what else I can tell you about what I want to achieve - let me know what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "Jquery" you can use the

```
$('#container').prepend( '<div class="post">Hi im a new post</div>' );
```

Instead of

```
$('#container').append( '<div class="post">Hi im a new post</div>' );
```

This will render the post as the first child element of #container instead of as the last.

Comment: Hmm, but then each new post would push all other posts one post down so the list would scroll constantly.Right?

Answer (score 0):

One idea, if you absolutely position your post list within another div, is to apply a negatively `top` value that is equal to the height of the new post.  To keep it simple, assume that all your posts are exactly 40px high then when a new post comes in set the `top` offset to whatever it was before minus 40px. I would be a little concerned about a "flicker" if this isn't handled well.

The same trick can apply to the `scrollTop` values if you're looking at your list within a scrolling window.

Comment: Thanks GSP! I had a similar idea but I was also concerned about a "flicker". I will give it a try though! :)